# How do you have specific values on a jQuery UI slider?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

My client has asked me to build a ui slider using jQuery but he wants the specific values 10,20,30,50,75,100,200.

I just have a basic setup of the slider

```
$(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:40,
    min: 10,
    max: 70,
    step: 10,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
      $(this).find("a.ui-slider-handle").text(ui.value).append('<br>miles');  
    }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

I just cant figure out what to do.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967372/jquery-slider-how-to-make-step-size-change and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681303/is-there-a-plugin-or-example-of-a-jquery-slider-working-with-non-equably-divisib for code examples

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857075/jquery-ui-slider-fixed-values

Comment: Thanks but there not exactly what I'm looking for, they're all sliders with ranges for example price between $10 and $20 my slider has 1 distinct value.

Answer (score 2):

I think i get what your saying, check the following fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/y9kbv/