# Slider, how to make “step” size change - JQuery

Tags: jquery, slider, step

I want to do something: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html

This example is in Flash but I'm doing mine in JQuery.

See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/NYZrz/9/

I'm having problem with the Slider "step" . In first link the value start in 1.0, the min=0.00010 and the max: 1000000

I want to horizontal Slider to look like:

0.00010 | 0.00012 | 0.00014 | 0.00017 | .... | 0.0090 | 0.011 | .... | 0.10 | 0.12 | 0.14 | ... | 1.0 | 1.2 | 1.4 | ... | 9.0 | 11 | 13 | 16 | .... | 5400 | ... | 1000000

But my code does not do this.

Can you help me??

Thanks....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857075/jquery-ui-slider-fixed-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `num.toPrecision(2)` instead of `toFixed` to always get 2 significant digits. I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/NYZrz/11/).

**EDIT**. To make numbers below 10, quite simply:

```
var _num = (num < 10) ? num.toPrecision(2) : Math.round(num)
```

(`num < 10` instead of `num < 1`)

I [updated your fiddle again](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/NYZrz/15/).

Comment: So now I did what you said but still the first value as an integer. It should be like this example: 1.0 | 1.2 | 1.4 | ... | 9.0 | 11 | .... | 1000000.

When I reduce the value of the slider is appearing right now ...0.00010

Thanks..

Comment: I did what you said and is working properly. Another question.

See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/5/

The star should be the same size as the sun at this link: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html, but this is not happening.

I'm not able to solve this.

Thanks,

Comment: It's best if you ask a separate question about this. It seems some math is involved...

Comment: Remember to always accept the correct answer (using the "check" icon on the left)